# Max heap in Java

Tags: java, heap

I'm just looking for some feedback on my implementation of a maxheap mostly relating to style. I'm trying to create good habits as I learn to program.

Note: for the sort method I was given the precondition that the passed in array never has empty/null elements and that it must be sorted in place.

```
public class Heap12<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements PQueue<E>{

  private E[] heap;                    // Backend data storage array
  private int size;                    // # elements in the heap
```

Private constructor that is used by the `sort()` method to heapify an array of objects type `E`. `Size` is initialized to 0 so that the objects in the array can be sorted in place by calling the `add(E e)` method.

`@param E[] e` - the array to be heapified

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Heap12(E[] e){
  this.heap = e;                     // Set heap array to passed in array
  this.size = 0;                     // Size HAS to be 0 initially
}
```

Public default no-arg constructor that initializes size to 0 and the backing array to a default capacity.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Heap12(){
  this.size = 0;                     // Default values
  this.heap = (E[]) new Comparable[5];
}
```

Public copy constructor that takes in another `Heap12<E>` object. It creates
a new `Heap12<E>` object that is a deep copy of the passed in object. The underlying objects of the backing array are shared, but each `Heap12` has its own instance variables.

`@param Heap12<E> o` - the `Heap12<E>` object to be copied

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Heap12(Heap12<E> o){
  this.heap = (E[]) new Comparable[o.heap.length];       
  this.size = o.size;                               // Copy size

  for(int i = 0; i < o.size(); i++){                // Copy each element
    this.heap[i] = o.heap[i];                       // reference
  }
}
```

Adds an element to this `Heap12` object. Does not accept null elements, will throw a `NullPointerException`. If the `Heap12` is at maximum capacity, the capacity will be doubled before adding the element.

`@param E e` - the element to be added to the `Heap12`

```
public void add(E e){
  if(e == null)                      // Check for null element add
    throw new NullPointerException();

  if(this.size() == heap.length)       
    expandHeap();                    // Double heap capacity if full

  heap[this.size()] = e;         // Add the element at the rightmost leaflet
  bubbleUp(this.size());         // Move it to its proper place
  size++;
}
```

Returns the largest element contained in the `Heap12` object (the root). Does not modify the heap.

`@return E` - the largest object (the object at the root)

```
public E peek(){
  return heap[0];
}
```

Removes the largest element in this heap (the root). If the heap is empty, null is returned.

`@return E` - the largest element (the root)

```
public E remove(){
  E toReturn;

  if(this.isEmpty())                 // Empty heap case
    return null;

  toReturn = heap[0];                // Return greatest element(root)
  heap[0] = heap[this.size() - 1];   // Put bottom rightmost at root
  heap[this.size() - 1] = null;      // Get rid of the copy
  size--;                            
  trickleDown(0);                    // Move the new root to its proper
                                     // place
  return toReturn; 
}
```

Determines if this `Heap12` is equal to the passed in object. Returns false if the passed in object is not a `Heap12`, the two `Heap12`'s have different sizes (# of elements), or if the two `Heap12` objects do not have the same underlying data, in the same order.

`@param Object` o - the object to compare this `Heap12` with `@return` boolean whether the two objects are equal

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
  if( !(o instanceof Heap12) )       // Type check
    return false; 

  Heap12 oQ = (Heap12) o;

  if(this.size() != oQ.size())       // Diff # elements means diff heaps
    return false;

  for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++){     // Loop through all the elements
    if( !(this.heap[i].equals(oQ.heap[i])) ) // if one is different
      return false;                          // heaps are not equal
  }

  return true;                       // If we get here, heaps are equal
}
```

Returns a hash code for this `Heap12` object. The code is the same for objects that contain the same elements in the same order.

`@return int` - the hash code of this `Heap12<E>`

```
public int hashCode(){
  int toReturn = 1;                   

 /* Add each elements hashCode to the total and multiples by 31 each time */
  for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++){ 
    toReturn = 31 * toReturn + heap[i].hashCode(); 
  } 
  return toReturn;
}
```

Checks to see if this `Heap12<E>` is empty (has no elements)

`@return boolean` - true if the `Heap12` is empty, false if not

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
  return size == 0;
}
```

Returns the number of elements in this `Heap12<E>` object as an int. `@return` - the number of elements in this `Heap12` object.

```
public int size(){
  return this.size;
}
```

Private helper method for `remove()`. This method reorders the underlying heap array after an element is removed so that the heap retains the max heap property and completeness.

`@param int parent` - the parent node index

```
private void trickleDown(int parent){
  int left = (2 * parent) + 1;       // Compute Left/Right child indices
  int right = (2 * parent) + 2;

  if(left > size - 1 )               // Base case: end of the heap
    return;

/* If right child is null or left child >= right child, compare left child
   to parent */ 
  if(heap[right] == null || heap[left].compareTo(heap[right]) >= 0){
    if(heap[left].compareTo(heap[parent]) > 0){
      swap(parent, left);            // If the left child is > parent swap
      trickleDown(left);             // Left index is now the parent index
    }
  }                                  // If the right child > parent
  else if(heap[right].compareTo(heap[parent]) > 0){
    swap(parent, right);             // Swap the parent and right child
    trickleDown(right);              // Right index is now the parent index
  }  
}
```

Private helper method for `add(E e)`. This method reorders the underlying heap array after an element is added so that the heap retains the max heap property and completeness.

`@param int child` - the child node index

```
private void bubbleUp(int child){
  int parent = (child - 1) / 2;      // Compute the parent index

  if(child == 0)                    // If we're at the root, stop bubbling
    return;                         // Added simply for clarity (not needed)

  if( heap[child].compareTo(heap[parent]) > 0 ){   // If child > parent
    swap(parent, child);            // Swap them
    bubbleUp(parent);               // parent is now the old child
  } 
}
```

Private helper method that swaps a parent node element and a child node element using a temp variable.

`@param int parent` - the index of the parent object

`@param int child` - the index of the child object

```
private void swap(int parent, int child){
  E temp = heap[parent];             // Store the parent
  heap[parent] = heap[child];        // Replace parent element with child
  heap[child] = temp;                // Replace child with the parent
}
```

Private helper method that doubles the capacity of the underlying array of this `Heap12` object. Used when trying to add an element to a heap where `size == capacity`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void expandHeap(){         // Create new array with double capacity
  E[] temp = (E[]) new Comparable[heap.length * 2]; 

  for(int i = 0; i < heap.length; i++){  
    temp[i] = this.heap[i];          // Copy all the references
  }
  this.heap = temp;                  // Update instance backing array
}
```

Static sort method that sorts the passed in array in place using a heap. The sorted array is in ascending order. The passed in array must be full and not contain any null elements.

`@param T[] a` - the array of objects to be sorted in ascending order

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(T[] a){
  Heap12<T> sorted = new Heap12<T>(a);    // Use unsorted array as heap 
                                          // backing array in new Heap12
  /* Add each array element to the heap, it will sort itself in place */
  for(int i = 0; i < sorted.heap.length; i++)
    sorted.add(sorted.heap[sorted.size()]);   // Size is initially 0

  /* Remove each heap element, put it at the end of the underlying array */
  while(sorted.size() > 0) 
    sorted.heap[sorted.size() - 1] = sorted.remove();   
}

}
```

Comment: @Quonux Nice formatting! Turns out really great! I like the "javadoc" format!

Answer (score 3):

One thing that I think need to be fixed is:

```
private Heap12(E[] e){
  this.heap = e;                     // Set heap array to passed in array
  this.size = 0;                     // Size HAS to be 0 initially
}
```

You need to copy it, otherwise the caller has reference to your array to corrupt it.

Comment: my bad, i did not realize it was private.. too much intervention of comments in the middle

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Heap12<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements PQueue<E>{
```

Don't name your Generic Parameters with a single letter, give them meaningful names wit the end `Type` so you can differenciate between variables and the Generic Parameters when you read the code.

Do not name your class Heap12, it it a heap for only 12 elements or only for 12 monkeys... nobody knows.

```
private Heap12(E[] e){
```

Don't name your variables with single letters, give them meaningful names.

```
if(e == null)                      // Check for null element add
throw new NullPointerException();
```

The comment is not needed, describe why you do something and not what.

Here maybe a assertion is more useful (don't forget to enale assertions with the `-ea` Parameter, its realy a shame that its not on by default), oh tese poor rockets which exploded because of this... anyways back to topic

```
if(this.isEmpty())                 // Empty heap case
return null;
```

the same as above, don't comment what your code does.

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
   return size == 0;
}
```

this is good, but we need also a method for the opposite

```
public boolean isNotEmpty(){
   return !this.isEmpty();
}
```

this makes reading of the code which uses this class easier.

```
swap(parent, child);            // Swap them
```

again, the same, don't comment what the code does

Comment: Thanks. The name of the class was not by choice but I appreciate the feedback.